# materialize wave effect problem in firefox 75.0

Tags: materialize

i am using material in my project. but in Firefox i have this problem and i could not found any similar topic in stackoverflow.

this is a sample. please after click on "Run Code Snippet" below, then click on "Full Page" button , then click on "Wave effect" button and hold to see wave effect ... wave effect not animate correctly and have problem.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://materializecss.com/bin/materialize.js"></script>
<link href="https://materializecss.com/css/ghpages-materialize.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<a class="waves-effect waves-light btn-large" href="#">Wave effect</a>
```

it's ok in opera and chrome...

gif of my problem: 
[image]

how can i do?

thanks for your helps.

Comment: Works absolutely fine in Firefox 75.0

Comment: @SeanDoherty please check topic again. i added gif of my problem. are you have this problem?

Comment: Hey, no sorry it works perfectly fine for me in Firefox - exactly as it should. Looks like a browser/machine specific problem - I wouldn't lose too much sleep over it. I'm running Mojave 10.14.6

Comment: thanks for your time, maybe it's not compatible with my hardware!